# Why is my asound status file's state parameter always set to RUNNING?

Tags: alsa

I need to use the state value in the status file in asound on a Raspberry Pi to check when the soundcard is making a noise or not, however for some reason, all the state values in all the status files are always RUNNING despite no sound being produced by any apps.

The status files also have owner_pid values set despite ps showing no processes with those pids currently running.

Any ideas why they're alwys RUNNING?

Have no contaners or virtualisation running..

If something set it to RUNNING and then died without setting it back, is it possible to reset the status manually? If so, what status?

Comment: RUNNING means that it's running; probably some sound server. But the process should be visible; is there any containerization/virtualization?

Comment: Nope, just on a raspberry pi. Concontainers or virtualisation..